# WPF Drag'n'Drop from Explorer working from Outlook not

Tags: wpf, powershell

In a Powershell WPF Application I have a Drag'n'Drop function with that code:
`$droppedfile=$_.Data.GetFileDropList()`
basically it's working fine if a file is dropped from Windows Explorer.
The problem is when you drag for example a attachement from Outlook (2016) $_.Data.GetFileDropList() is NULL. Has anyone an idea why?

Comment: Maybe one is ran as admin and other is not.

Comment: Definitely same user (no admin)

Comment: Same user... one app elevated and one not

Comment: I checked that now, unfortunately this isn't the problem.